# Resolve not returning from promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am having trouble working with promises and exporting to another file. I need to get some data from one file and return it to the other, but I can't seek to get it working. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Imap.js

var getCode = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  imaps.connect(config).then(function(connection) {

    return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function() {
      var searchCriteria = [
        'UNSEEN'
      ];

      var fetchOptions = {
        bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
        markSeen: false
      };

      return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function(results) {
        var subjects = results.map(function(res) {
          return res.parts.filter(function(part) {
            return part.which === 'HEADER';
          })[0].body.subject[0];
        });

        console.log(subjects[0]);
        resolve(subjects[0]);
      });
    });
  });
});

exports.getCode = getCode;

var imap = require('./imap.js');
impa.getCode.then(function(subj) {
  console.log(subj);
})
```

Comment: having `.then` inside a Promise executor is most certainly a sign of Promise constructor anti patterns

Comment: what is `imaps` and `config` in the promise? seems a random undefined variables would probably cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo between `var imap` and `impa.then`:

```
var imap = require('./imap.js');
imap.getCode.then(function(subj) {
  console.log(subj);
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh that was it! Thank you.

Comment: No problem @trever.

Comment: how is `getCode` a function? Am I having a stroke or something, I would've bet my life that `getCode` is a **Promise** - based on `var getCode = new Promise`

Comment: Sorry @JaromandaX, I didn't realise that - I'm used to functions returning promises.

Comment: yet, apparently this is the right answer - I'm still scratching my head as to **why** and even more so, **how** you managed to get it right when the code in the question would mean `imap.getCode` is a Promise not a Function :p - well done

Comment: I bet I know what the OP has done ... since there's this random `imaps` referenced in the promise executor

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX I realise that's the typo I mentioned in my answer. I'll edit it.

Comment: @JackBashford - no .. I'm talking about `var getCode = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  imaps.connect(config)` ... what is `imaps` and `config`? where did they come from? and why is a Promise suddenly a function?

Comment: To be honest, I think the reason this answers the question is simply `you had a typo between var imap and impa.then` ... OP hasn't bothered reading the rest, not realising you've turned a Promise into a function :p